# Why can't I connect to MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to connect through terminal using the connection string that mongodb atlas gives, I put the connection string then it asks me to put my password but the shell doesn't let me write anything.

This is what I get when I'm trying to connect.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the password is hidden completely. You are typing it, but it doesn't show any visible feedback. Once you type it in and press enter, it should let you know if you got in or if the password is incorrect.